# YoutubeSupportFragment on Chromecast remote display: Keeping in the background

Tags: android, android-fragments, chromecast, android-youtube-api

I am developing a ChromeCast app that instances a `YoutubeSupportFragment` in the presentation display.

My problem is, when the app goes background, Youtube video is stopped. I've traced that YoutubeSupportFragment's `onPause` pauses the video.

Is there a way to somehow attach the fragment lifecycle to the `CastRemoteDisplayLocalService` so fragment's `onPause` is not called?

I've tried to set the fragment as retained with `setRetainInstance` but no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there's a way of disabling onPause as it is at the core of the [Anroid lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).

Comment: Yes, I guess, but given the deep stuff involved in launching a persistent chromecast session (strong references to objects, services, singletons, interaction with internal google play libraries ...) maybe Google has some magic deep inside that somebody here knows about.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @noogui is correct in that you can't disable `onPause`. Making it easy to bind the state of fragments/activities to a persistent service would defeat the purpose of having fragments/activities; Android wants to be able to kill the `YoutubeSupportFragment` if memory runs low.

I haven't tried this, but there may be an alternative route. You can display an `iframe` in a receiver app per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945115/display-web-sites-and-web-apps-with-chromecast), and there is an [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for embedding the Youtube video player in an `iframe`. So instead of using the Cast `RemoteDisplayAPI`, why not write a custom receiver app to hold the video player? This should allow you to continue playing video whether or not the Android app is backgrounded.